# gitea clone using git@ prefix

Tags: ssh, gitea

I'm currently running a git server on my computer and trying to clone a repository using SSH.
The clone works if I use the prefix `gitea@host.net:repo.git` but fails if I use `git@host.net:repo.git`. The fail seems to be related to the user but I'm not sure about it. It just says :

```
git@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have the following config in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
# Gitea
Host host.net
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitea
```

With the correct private key in `~/.ssh/gitea` (I checked the sha256 hash in the web interface). In the web interface the cloning ssh url is `gitea@host.net:repo.git`

Is there a way to change that URL so that I can use `git@host.net:repo.git` instead or is it hard baked into gitea?

Comment: As far as the ssh part goes, replacing `User user` with `User gitea` will make ssh do what you need for the moment. Making gitea itself do what you want—use `git` rather than `gitea`—is a matter for gitea and/or sshd and/or your OS.